# How to get list of acronyms and list of symbols alphabetically sorted while using groups?

Tags: symbols, glossaries, acronyms, glossaries-extra

In a document I have both a list of acronyms and a list of symbols. Everything fine (both lists automatically alphabetically sorted) until I decided I needed two different groups in the list of symbols. I then implemented what suggested by leandriis's answer in [Grouping in list of symbols](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questioalttreegroupns/570803/grouping-in-list-of-symbols). The following MWE is from the same answer with some modifications:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[record, style=alttreegroup, nomain, symbols, acronyms]{glossaries-extra}

\newacronym{lsb}{LSB}{Least Significant Bit}
\newacronym{www}{WWW}{World Wide Web}
\newacronym{fft}{FFT}{Fast Fourier Transform}

\glsxtrnewsymbol[description={position}, group={first}]{x}{\ensuremath{x}}
\glsxtrnewsymbol[description={velocity}, group={first}]{v}{\ensuremath{v}}
\glsxtrnewsymbol[description={acceleration}, group={second}]{a}{\ensuremath{a}}
\glsxtrnewsymbol[description={time}, group={second}]{t}{\ensuremath{t}}
\glsxtrnewsymbol[description={force}, group={second}]{F}{\ensuremath{F}}

\renewcommand\glstreegroupheaderfmt[1]{\begingroup\centering \textbf{#1}\par\endgroup}
\glsfindwidesttoplevelname
\glsxtrsetgrouptitle{first}{Numbers and Arrays}
\glsxtrsetgrouptitle{second}{Sets}


\begin{document}

\printunsrtglossaries

\end{document}
```

Now, as `\printunsrtglossaries` already suggests, neither the list of acronyms nor the symbols in both groups are alphabetically sorted but the entries are rather shown in the
same order they're defined.

My question is: is there a way to get those entries automatically sorted while using groups or should I do it manually?